GPU stops working when graphics driver is installed
I am facing a weird problem for the last 2 months that my 3060 gets stuck on splash screen when I install nvidia drivers.
But there is more and it is slightly complicated to explain, please read full.
dxdiag output:
https://filebin.net/cv65bdlk3x2iwi8w/DxDiag.txt
I have tried so far:

Changing cables, switching ports, switching between DP and HDMI
Installed old drivers (half a dozen versions) after cleaning with DDU
Reinstalled windows 10/11 (lost count how many times)
Replaced both RAM sticks
Upgraded PSU (at one point I believed it was due to lack of power)
Installed Fedora and installed nvidia drivers on it to confirm it was not specific to windows and its drivers, it had the same problem
Took it to Gigabyte twice and they said it was perfectly fine and returned as is both times

What I have noticed:

Once I install nvidia drivers the only time it would show anything on screen is when Windows disables the official drivers and uses its basic display driver instead
I confirmed that even when my display is stuck on bootsplash, the PC is actually running, caps/num locks are working and I managed to shut it down with Alt - F4 > Enter without seeing anything on screen
When I took it to Gigabyte the first time it somehow worked there and I confirmed by installing nvidia drivers on their testing PC and running some benchmarks, so it's not triggered by load
I brought it home, tested it outside my cabinet with bare motherboard and it actually worked for a couple days, I assumed it was fixed and put it back in the cabinet and it again had the same problem the next day
I took it out to see if it worked outside again but problem still persisted, I reinstalled windows, disabled auto driver updates, put it back into case but kept all non essential components disconnected so practically how it would be outside the case, installed nvidia drivers and it still did not work
I went back to gigabyte, it again worked there so I brought it back and currently I am using it like this, too afraid to put it back inside case, it is running fine for the last 4 days with latest drivers.

I know it's messy but please ask questions for clarification, I am tired of not being able to use my PC.

My wild guess would be that there is something wrong with the ground of your PC, so when the screws of the GPU touch the case, something malfunctions. So, first check if your PC case is properly connected to the grounds of your PSU, and that all components are grounded. If that doesn't help, maybe have an electrician check the grounds of your power outlets.

The silicon that is utilized with a driver and without a driver is different. If you only experience a problem with drivers installed then your hardware is definitely the problem.

@Ramhound I did not know that, thank you. However I am still failing to fully understand how my PC case is a factor in this because I am unable to reproduce the problem at Gigabyte service center. 1NN has suggested something is wrong with the ground but then again shouldn't it fix itself when I try to run it outside the case again?
It is currently running fine since last 5 days with drivers outside the case, but if I put it back inside and the problem comes back it doesn't get fixed if I run it outside again, I have to take it to Gigabyte where it 'magically' starts working somehow.

GPU not functioning after installing drivers is a 99% tell that it's defective. If it's indeed running in your PC in some specific orientation but not another then it's again 99% tell that there's some broken connection and the best solution would be to find the problematic orientation of GPU (inside or outside of the case) and ask your service to reproduce it (it's not clear if you asked them to do so, they might have done bare minimum testing).
The most probable causes of problems which are not related to GPU are either a short circuit (if you don't have all motherboard stand-offs installed for example) or if the PCI-E slot is dirty inside. If neither is the case then GPU is almost guaranteed to be at fault.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Pyotr Baykalov thank you, didn't think about orientation specifically but now I may have discovered something helpful. I tested and found the GPU fans are starting and running smoothly when motherboard is outside the case and is laying flat on cardboard keeping gpu in a vertical position, but inside the case when fans are facing down they make a loud noise like something is being dragged on ground before starting to spin and it's considerably loud, enough to send strong vibrations through the entire otherwise sturdy metal case body.

@SamCooper while that sounds terrible it may be aging problem if your 3060 is old and has sleeve bearings which failed. Certainly not related to GPU failing when driver is installed.
